# Instagram api access toke is pulling incorrect user content

Tags: instagram

My Instagram client and access token are pulling the wrong username, and before you ask yes my client id and username are correct, the user photos it is pulling into my feed has my user name but with _ at the end yet it pulls all his photos into my site via my access token and client id (how is this possible).

I can not contact instagram about as there is no sufficient correspondents outlined on their sites.

I do not want to change my user name and need this looked at instagram, please assist.

Comment: You can use the Bug Tool to report this issue: http://instagram.com/developer/support/

Comment: OK so it fixed itself and now it is pulling the other users photos in again, what is going on with instagram!!!!!